# connect to access databae without dsn

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-access, odbc

I am using the following connection string to connect with my access database from vb.net application, but not get connected.

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq=D:\Projects\tempdb.mdb
```

It shows me following error

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

My code is below:

```
 Dim odbcConn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(m_connectionString)

 '' Build thr odbc Dataadapter
 Dim odbcAdpt As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(QueryToExecute, odbcConn)
 odbcAdpt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

Comment: try m_connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Projects\tempdb.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False;"

Answer (score 1):

I had connection problems. 
My project was not connecting to database because there were no default driver. 
I have solved this problem. 
If you are using 64-bit OS you must use 64-bit MS office. similarly if you are using 32-bit OS you must need 32-bit MS office. 
Be sure that you have all application of same number of bits. 
Hopefully it will solve your problem.